# What is the difference between the mp.task and mp.solution class?

Tags: mediapipe

I have encountered both while using `mediapipe`, but I could never really understand the difference between the two classes. Both classes provide great utilities to detect and draw landmark on images and videos, but to use which in which case, is tough to determine. Most communities and useres recommend `mp.solution`'s class, but in the documentation and `github mediapipe` leagacy note, `mp.task` is recommended. The `mediapipe github`, and documentation say that mp.task is the latest and updated version of landmark detection module. But in my time using it, it felt clanky and hard to use, specially for detection on video/live streams. It provides a new, Threaded/Asyncronous way of detecting and displaying landmarks on live streams, which seems more accurate, but is vastly slower than `mp.solutions` detection pattern.

If anyone knows about the differences other than what I mentioned, and some other insight related to the specified classes.

I tried to test performance of both side by side, but I could never get a deterministic result.

Currently I'm trying new things with `mp.task` class. If I figure something out. I will post it in the comments